# Data structure to store a step by step guide

Tags: javascript, optimization, data-structures, graph

I am trying to model in Javascript a step by step guide (think of any IKEA guide) where 
1. each step could be linked to one or multiple next steps, 
2. a step can have 0 or n dependencies on previous steps and 
3. there is always a final step. Something like this:

```
       o
      / \
o -> o   o -> o
      \ /
  o -> o
```

The first thing that comes to mind is a directed graph structure but since this graph has the uniqueness of having all nodes pointing "forward" I was wondering if there was a better approach. It feels like it should be some sort of hybrid of a tree and a graph.

Ultimately I would like to use this structure to optimize suggested execution plans. I wouldn't worry too much on optimizing for insertions, deletions, updates or queries since these guides will have always less than 100 steps. I am just looking for a data structure that would make coding "easier".

Things that I would query in this structure:

- What is the critical path?
- What are the dependencies/next steps for step X?
- What would be the most efficient way to parallelize/serialize the execution of these steps?

Answer (score 1):

A directed graph should be the easiest way to do it. Before you read the rest of the text, keep in mind that i didn't talk about paralellizing the data structure, because i'm not sure how to do it. Anyway, you are not going to deal with a lot of data so you won't have any efficiency issues.

We are going to store two arrays for each step: one for the next steps and one for the dependencies. The following operations will be supported:

1. Step insertion in O(1): just create two empty arrays for it
2. Dependency insertion in O(1): just add an entry in the end of the dependency/next step array of the involved steps
3. Step deletion in O(N): let S be the step to be deleted. Iterate over the dependency array of S, and for each element in the array, go to the next step array of this element and delete the entry containing S. Then iterate over the next step array of S, and for each element in the array, go to the dependency array of this element and delete the entry containing S. Then delete the two arrays related to S
4. Dependency deletion in O(N): just look for the entries related to the dependency you want to delete in the dependency/next step arrays and remove them
5. Check all dependencies and next steps for step S in O(N): just iterate over the two arrays related to step S
6. Find the critical path in O(N+M) where M is the total number of dependencies: we are going to run a dynamic programming algorithm: let f(v) be the longest path starting on vertex v. We can compute f(v) = 1 if v has no next steps, otherwise f(v) = max(f(u)+1) for every next step u. Run the dynamic programming algorithm for every step, and the critical path is the maximum among all longest paths.

Notice that some operations could be sped up using BSTs or hashtables, but since you are going to deal with small data i tried to keep it as simple as possible.